# hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport*

Tags: java, threadpool, stack-trace, java.util.concurrent, thread-dump

In application thread dump I can see threadpool with five threads like following:

```
"pool-1-thread-5" prio=10 tid=0x000000000101a000 nid=0xe1f in Object.wait() [0x00007f3c66086000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007b8e57af8> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:316)
    - locked <0x00000007b8e57af8> (a hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$SerializableLock)
    at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:994)
    at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
    at hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

But I don't use nothing like this directly and don't see anything like this in dependencies.

What is this (hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport) and why it used (application running on jdk 7)? Can I detect what part of application starting it?

Comment: If you can debug this app during startup, put a breakpoint on `hidden.edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`'s constructor, and see who calls it. If you can only debug it while it runs, breakpoint the `execute` and `submit` methods. The nature of the calling code will tell you why it is being used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This `edu.emory.mathcs.backport` package tree belongs to [backport-util-concurrent](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/index.php) which is a backport of `java.util.concurrent` to the older Java versions. The `hidden` prefix might have been added by tools like `maven-shade-plugin`.

If you're using Maven you can search for this dependency with:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent
```

Comment: It was dependency of maven itself on debian (http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libbackport-util-concurrent-java). And maven starts (and seems doesn't stop) 5 threads for downloading artifacts (http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html).